# Is it RESTful to remove the primary noun from a URL if the primary noun is provided in a header such as the Authorization header?

Tags: rest

While working on a RESTful API for a project my team and I noticed there was some duplication of data in our HTTP requests. The API is primarily concerned with setting data points for a Thing. A hypothetical example of the API right now is this:

```
POST /thing/{THING_ID}/datavalue
Authorization: Basic {THING_ID}:{SECRET API TOKEN}
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 14

{"foo": "bar"}
```

The THING_ID is always required in the Authorization header. I am wondering if it would still be valid REST if we removed the primary noun "THING_ID" from the URL completely.

```
POST /thing/datavalue
Authorization: Basic {THING_ID}:{TOKEN}
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 14

{"foo": "bar"}
```

Comment: "setting data points for a thing". Do you mean adding new data point entities to an existing thing, attaching existing data point entities to an existing thing, or something else?

Comment: I mean creating new data point entries for a Thing. Data entries are key, value, timestamp (explicit or implied)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a REST expert but I think your revised method is closer to being RESTful.  I don't think the original is RESTful.
Also if you are creating a new datavalue with post, shouldn't the url just be

```
/things
```

with the data value in the body. (assuming things is a resource)

and if you are replacing / updating a data value then put or patch

so in the case of a post things is the noun but in the case of a put or patch datavalue is the noun

I think to be RESTful the urls should be

to create a new data value

```
post to  /things
```

to replace a datavalue

```
put to /things/a_data_value
```

not access tokens or any thing else as part of the url itself

Comment: If `/things` is a collection resource of all things, `POST`ing to it would create a new thing, not a new datavalue. But maybe we are confused about what the resources really are.

Comment: I was assuming a data_value was a "thing",  at least that seems to be the intent given the revised post  "post thing/datavalue"

Comment: The revised version refers to the idea that the {THING_ID} has been extracted from the URL. There are N things in existence and each can have new data values. My question refers to whether it is valid to remove the {THING_ID} from the URL if the same information can already be inferred from a required header (Authorization)

Comment: So then the thing_id is a resource and it has datavalues.  I would say no then, it should not be removed from the url.  Can you turn it around and get the authorization from the url some how?

Comment: I guess it just seems weird if thing_id is secret it should not be part of a url, but then i guess it should not be a resource

Comment: I agree that it is a bit weird. This isn't an "API" so much as it is a communication protocol layered on HTTP for devices. (It's an IoT project). We could remove the ID from the Authorization header or introduce a API-TOKEN header as a replacement, but then we're just going out-of-band from the already present semantics in HTTP. I guess a 3rd option would be to invent a new Authorization scheme ala Authorization: AWS when using Amazon Web Services. Then we could keep the ID in the URL and remove it from the Authorization header while also eliminating duplication of data.

Comment: so I guess in your original method,  you might really say that the auth part in the token is not really redundant.  It just happens to match the thing_id, which you are hoping is secret, but in fact is a url.  Maybe you should change one of the two, say the token, and then somehow check that the request with the token is allowed to access the resource, like storing some property on the "thing"

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the principe of REST is that  a given request will allways give same result, and if acting on an object, you refer the object. When hiding `THING_ID` on the authorization header, you go on the side form REST because only the authorization header will be the difference between succeeding invocation of same query (URL + body) acting on different objects.

Answer (score 0):

How is a thing identified? If you only use

```
/thing/datavalue
```

there can only be *one* thing on which you can add data values.

If you have more than one thing, you must identify them. One way for this is to use the ID as part of the URL. You can `GET` a thing from

```
/thing/{THING_ID}
```

Now you can add a data value to this thing by `POST`ing to

```
/thing/{THING_ID}/datavalue
```

Headers **must not** be used to identify a resource.

Comment: "Headers must not be used to identify a resource." why not?

Comment: Because *only* the URI can be used for this. How do you bookmark a request with headers? You can't!